# How to merge two files containing lists to one file with two columns?

Tags: files, pipe, io-redirection, cat, columns

I have the file `mail.txt` which contains the list of some emails and the file `names.txt` that includes the names of those people accordingly. Now I want to combine these files to one files with the following structure:

```
name1: email1
name2: email2
.
.
.
```

Is it possible to achieve that with bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `paste` command as follows:

```
paste -d ': '  names.txt /dev/null mails.txt > result.txt
```

**Explanation of how it works:**

Paste does exactly what you want. And you can actually concatenate multiple columns with it but you can only pass one character as the delimiter between columns which is a problem in your case because ': ' are two characters.

However there is a workaround to that and you can use the `/dev/null` file which is basically a null file available in your system.

Now paste thinks you are concatenating three columns together the second of which being null so it puts the first character in your delimiter list (":") between `names.txt` and `null` and then it puts (" ") between `null` and `mail.txt` which adds up to `":" + "null" + " "` which is equal to `": "`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but just out of curiosity, is it also possible via `xargs`?

Comment: @tgwtdt I can't think of any way to achieve this with `xargs` because AFAIK xargs preserves the order of outputs.